# How to make a prediction on a RNN without training it every time

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am new to Neural networks and I have successfully trained an RNN but it takes a while to train the data. It would not be feasible for me to train the data every time I want to make a prediction. So the question is, how do I make the training data persistent in that the RNN does not have to train every time every time I make a prediction?

This is the code I am using...

```
 from sklearn import preprocessing
 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 from keras.models import Sequential
 from keras.layers import Dense
 from keras.utils.data_utils import pad_sequences


 class Predict:

TrainingData    = None
XScale          = None


def __init__(self,PredData,TrainingData):


    PreparedData = self.PrepareData(PredData,TrainingData)

    #set the training data

    self.Train(PreparedData)

    #split all of the training data into their respective variables


    X_train, X_val_and_test, Y_train, Y_val_and_test    = train_test_split(self.XScale, self.Y, test_size = 0.6)
    X_val, X_test, Y_val, Y_test                        = train_test_split(X_val_and_test, Y_val_and_test, test_size = 0.6)

    #define the model
    self.DefineModel(X_train, Y_train, X_val, Y_val)

    #do the prediction
    return self.predict(PredData)


def PrepareData(self, PredData,TrainingData):

    LNumber = 0

    for I in TrainingData:

        if(len(I) > LNumber):
            LNumber = len(I)


    PadData = pad_sequences(TrainingData, maxlen = LNumber, padding = 'post', truncating = 'post')



    return PadData

def Train(self,TrainData):

    min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

    self.X = TrainData[0:10]
    self.Y = TrainData[-10:]





    self.XScale = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(self.X)

def DefineModel(self,X_train, T_train, X_val, Y_val):

    self.model = Sequential([
                                Dense(32, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (10,)),
                                Dense(32, activation = 'relu'),
                                Dense(1, activation  = 'sigmoid'),
                            ])

    self.model.compile(     optimizer   = 'sgd',
                            loss        = 'binary_crossentropy',
                            metrics     = ['accuracy']
                            )

    self.model.fit(         X_train, Y_train,
                            batch_size = 32, epochs = 100,
                            validation_data = (X_val, Y_val))


def predict(self,PredData):

    Self.Prediction = model.predict(PredData)
```

Comment: See tensorflow's [Checkpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint) and [SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments you can use [SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model?hl=en) to save your entire architecture + weights. I suggest you having a look at this page on how to [Save and load Keras models](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize?hl=en).

Basically you just need to save like this:

```
self.model.save('path/to/location')
```

And to restore later on:

```
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('path/to/location')
```

Also if your training is quite long, you can also think about saving checkpoints of the best model so far, using the callback [`tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint). You create the callback and add it to your fit:

```
checkpoint_filepath = '/tmp/checkpoint'
model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_accuracy',
    mode='max',
    save_best_only=True)

# Model weights are saved at the end of every epoch, if it's the best seen so far.
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=100,
          validation_data=(X_val, Y_val), callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback])
```

If your train crashes or got interrupted you can re-load the best weights like this:

```
# The model weights (that are considered the best) are loaded into the model.
model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)
```

Note that if you are re-starting your script you will have to re-create the model object: `load_weights` does not re-create the architecture for you like it does `load_model`. But it is just a matter, in your case, of doing first:

```
self.model = Sequential([
       Dense(32, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (10,)),
       Dense(32, activation = 'relu'),
       Dense(1, activation  = 'sigmoid'),
])
```